# How do I put conditions around Proc Freq statements in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have the following statement

```
Proc Freq data =test;
tables gender;
run;
```

I want this to generate an output based on a condition applied to the gender variable. For example - if count of gender greater than 2 then output.

How can I do this in SAS?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you mean an output dataset, you can put a `where` clause directly in the output dataset options.

```
Proc Freq data =sashelp.class;
  tables sex/out=sex_freq(where=(count>9));
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of how you can accomplish this only using `proc freq` but you can redirect the output to a data set and then print the results.

```
proc freq data=test;
tables gender / noprint out=tmp;
run;

proc print data=tmp;
where count > 2;
run;
```

Alternatively you could use `proc summary`, but this still requires two steps.

```
proc summary data=test nway;
class gender;
output out=tmp(where=(_freq_ > 2));
run;

proc print data=tmp;
run;
```